# How to use regex to search in a string

Tags: python, regex

I am now using regex to handle some string, now I have a special string that is not easy to use regex to handle. below are some sample string. **TP-LINK is a sample, it can be other router vendor with similar format**.

```
TP-LINK Wireless Range Extender WA810RE 
TP-LINK Wireless WA850RE  
TP-LINK Wireless Range Extender WA850RE  
TP-LINK Wireless Range Extender WA890RE
```

As you can see in above string, I want to get `TP-LINK` which will use `TL` instead, and `WA850RE`, then the final result is `TLWA850RE`

I am using look ahead in regex, but it seems not work.

```
re1 = 'TP-LINK Wireless Range Extender WA850RE'
m1 = re.search('(T(?=P-)L(?=INK)(.+)(WA\\w+))', re1)
```

Comment: Is it always `WA850RE`? What does the string normally look like?

Comment: First mistake: You got the parameters backwards. It's `re.search(pattern, string)`. Also, there are no `\"` _in_ the string, are there?

Comment: Thanks, I update it in OP.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in the string?

Comment: I don't think you need to enclose your string in `'"  "' ` just use  single quotes `' '`

Comment: Show your final output..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes about your original regex:

- a lookahead only makes sense at the end of the string; you were probably looking for a non-capturing group, e.g. `T(?:P-)` instead of `T(?=P-)`, but you don't even need those if they appear exactly once (i.e. if there's no need to put a `*`, `+` or `?` behind the group)
- those `"` are not actually a part of the string, so you should remove those from the regex
- only put capturing groups around those parts that you want to use in the result.

Put together, you could do this:

```
>>> m = re.search(r'(T)P-(L)INK.+(WA\w+)', re1)
>>> ''.join(m.groups())
'TLWA850RE'
```

However, if you want to abbreviate the string, you should just match the string and extract the important parts using a regex, and then prefix the result. There's no need to capture the `TP-LINK` part in a group if it's always the same anyway. This will also further simplify your regex.

```
>>> m = re.search(r'TP-LINK.+(WA\w+)', re1)
>>> "TL" + m.group(1)
'TLWA850RE'
```

And then similar regexes for the other cases (Netgear, Cisco, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Let me quickly ask, why would you want such a regex. If it is a pattern, that appears on many strings you work with, that all apply to a certain rule and the result of the process is always according to the rules to provide, than a regex may be the right tool.

For example with data like 100s of:

```
TP-LINK Wireless Range Extender WA850RE > TLWA850RE
CI-CISCO WLAN Extender CWL12345 > CCWL12345
NG-NETGEAR Wifi Ext NG345 > NGNG345
```

To achive that, you can use:

```
(?m)^(\w)\w+-(\w)[\w\s]+?([A-Z0-9]+)$

(?m) perform each pattern between "^" and "$" on each line
^(\w) catch the first character of the first word starting the line
\w+ match any other following word characters
- match a dash
(\w) match the first character following the dash
[\w\s]+? match any words and whitespace as few(non-greedy) as possible
([A-Z0-9]+)$ match any combination of capitals and numbers till EOL
```

But if you just have some fixed rules, that appear on strings that start with an exactly equal sequence and the regex should just be a complex way to  perform a static substitution, your tool may be wrong. As for example with:

```
TP-LINK Wireless Range Extender WA850RE > TLWA850RE
TP-LINK Wireless Range Base WA950RB > TLWA950RB
TP-LINK Wireless Access Point WA87AP > TLWA870AP
```

In the latter case, you should stick to simple text-substitution, in the first case, a regex may be suitable.

In other words, I doubt that a regex you want is the right tool for your job.

Comment: actually, I am your first case sample.

Answer (score 0):

This below regex will help you to find the desired match:

```
(\w)\w-(\w)\w+ .* (\w+)$
```

with substituion

```
\1\2\3
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jU5iB0/1)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**  this is use for any items..

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\w)\w*-(\w).+(\b\w+)', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"TP-LINK Wireless Range Extender WA850RE\nCI-CISCO WLAN Extender CWL12345\nNG-NETGEAR Wifi Ext NG345"
subst = u"\1\2\3"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jU5iB0/2)**